# How to insert border-bottom to span with Ooxml?

Tags: javascript, ms-word, openxml, office-addins

In my Ooxml style, I need to underline something with `border-bottom: 1px solid red`. How can I achieve this?

```
<w:style w:type="character" w:styleId="custom_underline">
        <w:name w:val="custom_underline"/>
        <w:basedOn w:val="DefaultParagraphFont"/>
        <w:uiPriority w:val="99"/>
        <w:unhideWhenUsed/>
        <w:rsid w:val="00B00697"/>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:color w:val="0563C1" w:themeColor="custom_underline"/>
          <!-- <w:bottom w:val="outset" w:sz="18" w:color="Red" /> Not Working --> 
          <!-- <w:u w:val="wave" w:color="Red" /> Not suitable -->
        </w:rPr>
      </w:style>
```

Comment: Create a very simple example in a Word document, as a user. Save, close. The open this in the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool. That will show the underlying Word Open XML that can then be incorporated in what you're trying to do.

Comment: @CindyMeister, i need insert this style with help office js

Comment: I understand you want to use the ooxml part of the Word JS API to insert this. For that you need the valid Word Open XML. My previous comment explained how you find out what that is. It's the same steps anyone else would have to do to get this information...